# Convert Shell Script into PowerShell Script

Tags: bash, powershell

So i have this Shell Script and I'm trying to convert into PowerShell Script

The "task" is to read the text file line by line and give back an average of the 4 number connected to the name given in argument

Text file:

```
.... ... . . . .
John Big 1 2 4 5
.... ... . . . .
```

EXAMPLE:

```
if arg is "John Big" it should give back 3
```

Shell Script:

```
while read -r fname lname a b c d;
do
  x="$fname $lname"

  if [ "$x" = "$1" ]
  then
    avg=$(( (a + b + c + d) / 4 ))
    echo $avg
    break
  fi
done <class.txt
```

PowerShell:

```
$TextFile = Get-Content .\class.txt
foreach($line in $TextFile){
   $fname,$lname,[int]$a,[int]$b,[int]$c,[int]$d =$line.split(' ')
   $x = "$fname $lname"
   $avg = (($a + $b + $c + $d) / 4)
   if($x = $args[0]){
    echo $avg
    break
  }
}
```

Please help me edit this PowerShell script

Comment: Since you already have a Powershell version: What exactly is not working? [Hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1): Try `$x -eq $args[0]` instead of `$x = $args[0]`

Comment: I'm new to PowerShell and when i ran this code it always printed 3(only read the first line) @OcasoProtal

Comment: That's because you are using a wrong [comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1) in your if. Use `-eq` (comparison) instead of `=` (Assignment!)  will do the trick.

Comment: I tried it but now it just prints the argument @OcasoProtal

Comment: Just tested it with the fix, it works fine for me. How do you call the script? Use quotes around the argument: `yourscript.ps1 "John Big"`!

Answer (score 0):

You used an assignment in your if-condition instead of an [comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1). So when you replace that `=` with `-eq` everything works fine:

```
$TextFile = Get-Content .\class.txt
foreach ($line in $TextFile) {
    # Write-Host $line
    $fname, $lname, [int]$a, [int]$b, [int]$c, [int]$d = $line.split(' ')
    $x = "$fname $lname"
    $avg = (($a + $b + $c + $d) / 4)
    # Write-Host $avg
    if ($x -eq $args[0]) {
        Write-Host $avg
        break
    }
}
```

I used `Write-Host` instead of `echo` and added some (commented) lines with `Write-Host` to print some "debug data". Just uncomment to see what happens inside your script when you run it.